# Rails 2.3.18 upgrade to 3.2.21 im getting "no method 'with_connection'" error on active record queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im in the middle of performing an edge ruby and rails update for a web app built in rails 2.3.18 and running ruby 1.9.3.

I have been incrementally been updating the rails version and fixing breaks and things have been moving forward at a steady pace. I have rails 3.2.21 running and Ive just done the first ruby update to 2.0.0-p648.

I cannot find literally anything about this error online so im hoping ill have better luck here. Thx in advance.

This is the line in my controller that triggers this error. Keep in mind this is not my code. Im updating a 8 year old system.

```
@blogs = WpPosts.where(post_status: 'publish').order(post_date: :desc).limit(3)

undefined method `with_connection' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x007fc08067ae60>
```

This error can be made to happen on any active record call, including

```
WpPosts.all
```

The database Im using is mysql and im using the mysql2 gem with adapter. Here is my gemfile.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

gem 'bigdecimal',                  '1.1.0'
gem 'business_time'
gem 'calendar_date_select',        '2.0.0'
gem 'gibbon',                      '1.1.3'
gem 'holidays'
gem 'httparty',                    '0.13.1'
gem 'io-console',                  '0.3'
gem 'json',                        '1.8.1'
gem 'mini_portile',                '0.5.0'
gem 'minitest',                    '5.3.4'
gem 'multi_json',                  '1.10.1'
gem 'multi_xml',                   '0.5.5'
gem 'journey'

gem 'mysql2',                      '~> 0.3.21'

gem 'nokogiri',                    '1.6.1'
gem 'parseexcel',                  '0.5.2'
gem "iconv",                        "~> 1.0.3"
gem 'pdf-core',                    '0.6.1'
gem 'pdfkit',                      '0.8.2'

gem 'rubyzip',                     '1.1.6'
gem 'rufus-scheduler',             '3.0.9'
gem 'sanitize',                    '2.1.0'
gem 'saxerator',                   '0.9.4'
# TODO address ssl_requirement error
# gem 'ssl_requirement',             '0.1.0'
gem 'thread_safe',                 '0.3.3'
gem 'ttfunk',                      '1.4.0'
gem 'tzinfo',                      '0.3.29'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary',          '0.9.9.3'
gem 'rails_legacy_mapper'

group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

# Needed for the new asset pipeline
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  # gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
end

# jQuery is the default JavaScript library in Rails 3.1
# gem 'jquery-rails'
```

At this stage I keep getting the following error.

```
undefined method `with_connection' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x007fc08067ae60>
```

Here is the stack trace

```
undefined method `with_connection' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x007fc08067ae60>


    arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:16:in `accept'
arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:381:in `find_first'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
app/views/default/start.html.erb:246:in `_app_views_default_start_html_erb__1835693497152716952_70232382243240'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/sidylife/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__838951966072540285__process_action__2683730459786019710__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
pdfkit (0.8.2) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__155349648496822945__call__1222344604970663536__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.21) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/sidylife/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/sidylife/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/sidylife/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally was able to figure this out after long meditation. I went ahead and skipped this version and just pushed on hoping it would resolve itself. Which kinda did and didnt happen. I got rid of this error by pushing forward to rails 4... but Another active record error kept popping up. So @tallboy looked at my gemfile and gemfile.lock to help me make sense of this new error and I realized at that point that the version of arel that my gemfile was locked to was an old 2.2.3 version.

Then I had a flashback to this problem and realized that the first two lines of the stacktrace on this error were call to the arel lib.

So I came back to my 3.2.xx branch of rails and updated to the proper arel lib and BOOM. it works now like a charm. Rails 3.2.22.5 is up and running by just changing the arel version to 3.0.3

Once again... @tallboy saved my backside!

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to downgrade your `mysql2` gem, since current version is a *very* young one.

Start with

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3', '= 0.3.18'
```

and maybe even

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3', '= 0.3.15'
```

I believe this should do the trick.

Comment: When i try your first solution I get the same error after bundle install. When I try the second solution I get a gem load error "Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Mysql2::SECURE_CONNECTION

Comment: The plot thickens. Now you need to downgrade your MySQL to 5.6 (or even 5.5, I do not remember exactly.)

Comment: No Cigar :/ Im just going to keep going with the upgrade for now and hope this bug clears itself up throughout the process.